# Waiting on a condition in a reentrant lock

Tags: java, synchronization

The following code is taken from the [JavaDoc of `Condition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html):

```
class BoundedBuffer {
  final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
  final Condition notFull  = lock.newCondition(); 
  final Condition notEmpty = lock.newCondition(); 

  final Object[] items = new Object[100];
  int putptr, takeptr, count;

  public void put(Object x) throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lock();
    try {
      while (count == items.length) 
        notFull.await();
      items[putptr] = x; 
      if (++putptr == items.length) putptr = 0;
      ++count;
      notEmpty.signal();
    } finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }

  public Object take() throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lock();
    try {
      while (count == 0) 
        notEmpty.await();
      Object x = items[takeptr]; 
      if (++takeptr == items.length) takeptr = 0;
      --count;
      notFull.signal();
      return x;
    } finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  } 
}
```

Imagine 2 threads, *Consumer* and *Producer*, one using `take`, one `put` on a single instance of `BoundedBuffer`.

Let's say *Consumer* goes first, runs `take()` in which he locks the `lock` and now loops on `notEmpty.await();`.

How can now *Producer* possibly get into the `put()` method past locking the `lock`, which is already held by the *Consumer*?

What am I missing here? Is the `lock` "temporarily released" while the thread is waiting on one of its conditions? And what does the *reentrancy* of the lock mean, exactly?

Comment: I was about two ask exactly the same question with exactly same example on JavaDoc :) Saved me from losing time.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Both `Lock` and `synchronized` allow a thread to give up the lock when waiting and another thread can obtain the lock. To stop waiting, a thread have to re-acquire the lock.

Note: They don't release it fully and if you take a stack trace you can have multiple threads which appear to be holding the lock at once, but at most one of them will be running (the rest will be blocking)

From [Condition.await()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html#await--)

> The lock associated with this Condition is atomically released and the current thread becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until one of four things happens:
>
> - Some other thread invokes the signal() method for this Condition and the current thread happens to be chosen as the thread to be awakened; or
> - Some other thread invokes the signalAll() method for this Condition; or
> - Some other thread interrupts the current thread, and interruption of thread suspension is supported; or
> - A "spurious wakeup" occurs.
>
> In all cases, before this method can return the current thread must re-acquire the lock associated with this condition. When the thread returns it is guaranteed to hold this lock

Comment: Could you provide a link to the relevant documentation?

Comment: @PeterLawrey  `(the rest will be waiting)` or blocking? I think they should be in block state`?

Comment: Can you explain this sentence: "Both Lock and synchronized temporarily allow others to obtain the lock when they are waiting." It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Chin When the holder of a lock is waiting, it releases the lock to be able to be held by another thread.

Comment: I guess the confusing part is that in your sentence "others" and "they" do not refer to the same entities.

Answer (score 6):

As far as re-entrancy, this means that a thread that holds a certain lock can re-acquire the same lock again. If this wasn't so, a `synchronized` method would not be able to call another `synchronized` method of the same object.

Re-entrancy is not involved in the understanding of your problem.

Comment: Exactly. Sometimes also the term "recursive lock" is used for reentrant locks, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex).

Answer (score -1):

I  tested below code with single monitor and below always performs better - Tested on 2 core machine, Condition performance is 10-15% below on an average

```
 final Object sync = new Object();
  AtomicInteger add=new AtomicInteger();
  AtomicInteger remove=new AtomicInteger();
   final Object[] items = new Object[1];
   int putptr, takeptr, count;        

 public void add(Object x) throws InterruptedException {
       add.incrementAndGet();

     synchronized (sync) {

       while (count == items.length)
         sync.wait();
       items[putptr] = x;
       if (++putptr == items.length) putptr = 0;
       ++count;
       sync.notify();
        }
   }

   public Object remove() throws InterruptedException {
       remove.incrementAndGet();

     synchronized (sync) {

       while (count == 0)
         sync.wait();
       Object x = items[takeptr];
       if (++takeptr == items.length) takeptr = 0;
       --count;
       sync.notify();
       return x;

       }
   }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final BoundedBuffer bf=new BoundedBuffer();

    Thread put =new Thread(){
        public void run(){
        try {
            while(true)
            bf.add(new Object());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
        }

    };
    put.start();

    Thread take= new Thread(){
        public void run(){
        try {
        while(true)
            bf.remove();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
        }

    };
    take.start();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
        put.interrupt();
        take.interrupt();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    System.out.println("add:"+bf.add);
    System.out.println("remove:"+bf.remove);
```